# Attempt to manually update 8.1 starts windows 10 install- how do i stop it?

Tags: windows-8.1

I'm in a rural area with only dialup.  I update my windows 8.1 at the library with wifi.  I have a Toshiba i5 core, never any problems. Ever since I accepted the notification for windows 10 I have not been able to download the updates for 8.1 without it starting to download windows 10 first.  I uncheck the box on win10 update that they default to on the optional download list.  I have uninstalled the KB3035583 update, rebooted, and now I do not get the notification, but it still tries to download win10 first.  I always stop it within a second, when I see it starting.  I've got about 22 updates waiting now for 8.1.  Is there a work around to getting them?

Answer (score 1):

Better do all your updates before going any further. And since you uninstall the KB3035583 update, this is why you no longer have access to the icon and notification on the tray.

Another option for you, will be to ask a friend who is on high speed to download the ISO and burn it to a DVD for you and then do the update manually from that DVD. ISO can be download here : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

If you really don't want to update to Windows 10, this might work to stop it :

1. Locate the registry key
   :[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\OSUpgrade]
2. Locate the key Name = "AllowOSUpgrade” (without the quotes), and set
   the Value = 0x00000000.

That said, there's no reason you shouldn't install Windows 10. It free until July 29 2016, after that, you'll have to pay for it.

Comment: Even though I have Windows 10 here, I could think of plenty of reasons why you wouldn't want to install it. One of them is that I have had issues with the Microsoft keyboard and mouse here and the Keyboard and Mouse center software that came with it. Still not listed as Windows 10 compatible, how sick is that?